# Drag and drop: Turns white on Drag start

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, svelte

I am trying to create a draggable element that can be dragged into a dropzone.

When the element is dragged (onDragStart), there is a small time when the element turns white and then it becomes normal as shown in the two pictures below.

On drag

[image: On drag]

After dragging it a little

[image: After dragging it a little]

I am using Svelte and here is the code I've used:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { draggable } from "../shared/functions/draggable" 
    import { dropzone } from "../shared/functions/dropzone";

    let components: Array<string> = [
        "1",
        "2",
        "3",
        "4"
    ]
</script>

<div class="main">
    <div class="components">
        {#each components as component}
            <h1 use:draggable={component}>{component}</h1>
        {/each}
    </div>
    
    <div class="render" use:dropzone={
        {
            onDropped(componentId) {
                console.log(componentId)
            }
        }
    }>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>        
    </div>
</div>
```

draggable:

```
export function draggable(node: HTMLHeadingElement, data: string) {
    let state = data;
    
    node.draggable = true;
    node.style.cursor = 'grab';

    function dragStart(e) {
        e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', state);
    }

    node.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);

    return {
        update(data: string) {
            state = data;
        },
        destroy() {
            node.removeEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);
        }
    };
}
```

dropzone:

```
export function dropzone(node: HTMLHeadingElement, options) {
    let state = {
        dropEffect: 'move',
        dragOverClass: 'droppable',
        ...options
    };

    function dragEnter(e) {
        e.target.classList.add(state.dragOverClass);
    }

    function dragLeave(e) {
        e.target.classList.remove(state.dragOverClass);
    }

    function dragOver(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = state.dropEffect;
    }

    function drop(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const data = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');
        e.target.classList.remove(state.dragOverClass);
        state.onDropped(data, e);
    }

    node.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter);
    node.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeave);
    node.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver);
    node.addEventListener('drop', drop);
}
```

Is taking time to create a new element that can be hovered? Why is it happening in the first place?

You can try out this example to see it for yourself: https://svelte.dev/repl/adf5a97b91164c239cc1e6d0c76c2abe?version=3.14.1

Comment: Just tested the REPL on Chrome and Safari and everything was perfectly rendered?

Comment: That REPL works fine, but it doesn't seem to have much relation to the code you've shared above. Did you mean to share a different REPL?